# Prove that if $z\notin E$ and $E$ is closed, then $inf\{d(z,y):y\in E\}>0$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(S,d)$ be a metric space with $E \subset S,\ E\neq \emptyset$

(a) Prove that if $z\notin E$ and $E$ is closed, then $inf\{d(z,y):y\in E\}>0$

(b) Prove that $inf\{d(x,y):x\in E, y\notin E\}=0$

---

This is tripping me up and I am not exactly sure where to even begin with it. For part (b), I have an idea that this has something to do with x and y both being on the border or something? I know the distance between x and y can only be 0 if x=y...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) $z\not \in E$ so $z \in S \setminus E$ - an open set. There exists a ball, $B$, of radius $\epsilon > 0$ such that $z \in B \subset S\setminus E$. So $\inf\{d(z,y) \colon y \in E\} \geqq \epsilon > 0$.

(b) Take $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x$ on the boundary of $E$. Then the ball of radius $\frac{1}{n}$ centred at $x$ intersects $S\setminus E$. So $\inf \{ d(x, y) \colon x \in E , y \not \in E \} \leqq \frac{1}{n}$. Since $n$ arbitrary we are done.

Comment: For (b), how can x be on the boundary? I'm reading this as E is an open set for part (b)... are you interpreting it differently?

Comment: Okay so $x$ in my proof doesn't have to be in $E$ but the ball of radius $1/n$ centred at $x$ will intersect both $E$ and $S\setminus E$ so $\inf \{ 
d(x,y) \colon x \in E, y \not \in E \} \leqq 1/n$